# Pass a file glob to an Ansible role

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to pass a list of file paths to a role, so that it can process them using `with_items`. The use case is having a generic role (logstash) that can be given a set of configuration files, which it'll place in the right directory on the host.

**Role use (ideally)**

```
- hosts: logstash
    roles:
      - role: logstash
        logstash_conf_files:
          - ../analytics/logstash/*.conf
```

**Task in role**

```
- name: Create Logstash configuration files.
  template:
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: "/etc/logstash/conf.d/{{ item | basename }}"
  with_items: logstash_conf_files
  notify: restart logstash
```

I know that I can explicitly list out the filenames in a list for `logstash_conf_files`, but I'd rather have it pick them up automatically from a set of directories. It'll also work if the configuration files are located inside the role, but this would make the role non-reusable.

What's the recommended way to achieve this?

EDIT: @tedder42's solution works if I use a directory relative to `roles/logstash/files/`:

```
- hosts: logstash
    roles:
      - role: logstash
        logstash_conf_files: ../../../../analytics/logstash/*.conf
```

In role task:

```
- name: Create Logstash configuration files.
  template:
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: "/etc/logstash/conf.d/{{ item | basename }}"
  with_fileglob: logstash_conf_files
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fully working example.

### configuration

```
cat glob.yml # (playbook)
---
- name: glob
  connection: local
  hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - { role: ls, list_dir: "/etc/*" }

cat roles/ls/tasks/main.yml
---
- name: list files
  command: ls {{item}}
  with_fileglob: list_dir
```

### execution

$ ansible-playbook -i hosts.ini glob.yml

```
PLAY [glob] ******************************************************************* 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
ok: [127.0.0.1]

TASK: [ls | list files] ******************************************************* 
changed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=/etc/afpovertcp.cfg)
changed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=/etc/aliases)
changed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=/etc/aliases.db)
changed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=/etc/asl.conf)
[...]
```

Comment: This is really close, but I need to be able to use relative paths in the playbook, since it's using files from the rest of a source repository. This only works when using an absolute path. Is there a way to work around this in `with_fileglob`?

Comment: yeah @robbles- is 'analytics' a role, so you have roles/analytics/files/logstash/foo.conf? lemme know, I can repro with a relative path if you tell me the structure.

Comment: it's not a role, just a non-ansible-related directory elsewhere in the repository. It looks like I can use a path relative to `roles/logstash/files` with this solution.